# How do I modify a ListTile so it has a widget for a chip or chips? (in Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

As you know, the ListTile comes packaged with 4 widgets:
a) title:
b) subtitle:
c) leading: can be an icon or text I suppose
d) trailing: can be an icon or text I suppose

But I want to add a 5th:

e) chipSection: [which accepts a row of chips]

Can someone advise me on how I can establish this? What do you recommend??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can't add 5th option directly without changing source code which I wouldn't recommend.
There are few options:

1. Use a Column and make ListTile and ChipSection it's children. Tho in this case you have to add elevation to ChipSection.
2. Make a Custom Widget say myListTile, add arguments for title, leading, subtitle,trailing and chip Section.
   Inside Custom widget return a  Card Widget, add Column as its child, and then add:
   Icon/Test widget for leading,
   Text widget for Title
   Another Text Widget for subtitle
   Icon/Test Widget for Trailing
   Your chip section 
   as columns, children. 
   Use Padding + Column's mainaxisaligment property to manage their alignment.

Comment: Thank you Raj. Yes.. i came to the same conclusion as yourself. By the way, option 1 does not work

Comment: Well, the first option may not be what you required. But, Happy to know your problem is solved :)